# How to remove duplicate nested objects comparing their values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I wanted to know how can I remove duplicate nested objects comparing their values.

```
 const values = [ 
    { i: 2, j: 4, l: 36 },
    { i: 4, j: 2, l: 36 },
    { i: 0, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 0, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 1, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 1, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 1, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 3, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 5, l: 28 },
    { i: 3, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 3, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 4, j: 1, l: 28 },
    { i: 4, j: 3, l: 28 },
    { i: 4, j: 5, l: 28 },
    { i: 5, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 5, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 0, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 0, j: 3, l: 20 },
    { i: 0, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 1, j: 3, l: 20 },
    { i: 1, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 3, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 3, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 5, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 5, j: 3, l: 20 } 
 ];
```

In this case i want to remove the second duplicate objects (that satisfy the 
  below conditions) and let the first one :

```
 value[i].i === value[j].j && value[i].j === value[i].i && value[i].l === 
 value[j].l
```

Wanted result :

```
 const result = [
    { i: 2, j: 4, l: 36 },
    { i: 0, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 0, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 1, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 1, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 3, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 5, l: 28 },
    { i: 3, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 4, j: 5, l: 28 },
    { i: 0, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 0, j: 3, l: 20 },
    { i: 0, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 1, j: 3, l: 20 },
    { i: 1, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 3, j: 5, l: 20 }
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your second duplicate array ?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question I mean duplicate objects in one array.

Comment: using Object.values  compare two object and delete Splice it from array.

Comment: Actually Your second element is not duplicate.

Comment: It's a duplicate in the sens where we take into consideration the mentionned conditions.

Comment: I'm reconsidering the duplicates. Is that a typo in the code? Should `value[i].j === value[i].i ` be `value[i].j === value[j].i`? I mean you want to remove an item if 1) `i` of one item === `j` of another 2) vice versa 3) `l` is same

Comment: Exactly what i want !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle the condition with the key swap where

`value[i].i === value[j].j && value[i].j === value[i].i`

you can make two functions that calculate a value you test for equality. One without the swap and one with. You can add the original to a set and then in the filter test if the swapped version exists.

For example:

```js
const values = [ 
  { i: 2, j: 4, l: 36 },
  { i: 4, j: 2, l: 36 },
  { i: 0, j: 2, l: 28 },
  { i: 0, j: 4, l: 28 },
  { i: 1, j: 2, l: 28 },
  { i: 1, j: 4, l: 28 },
  { i: 2, j: 1, l: 28 },
  { i: 2, j: 3, l: 28 },
  { i: 2, j: 5, l: 28 },
  { i: 3, j: 2, l: 28 },
  { i: 3, j: 4, l: 28 },
  { i: 4, j: 1, l: 28 },
  { i: 4, j: 3, l: 28 },
  { i: 4, j: 5, l: 28 },
  { i: 5, j: 2, l: 28 },
  { i: 5, j: 4, l: 28 },
  { i: 0, j: 1, l: 20 },
  { i: 0, j: 3, l: 20 },
  { i: 0, j: 5, l: 20 },
  { i: 1, j: 3, l: 20 },
  { i: 1, j: 5, l: 20 },
  { i: 3, j: 1, l: 20 },
  { i: 3, j: 5, l: 20 },
  { i: 5, j: 1, l: 20 },
  { i: 5, j: 3, l: 20 } 
];



const makeKey = (a) => `${a.i}_${a.j}_${a.l}`  // original key
const makeKey_test = (a) => `${a.j}_${a.i}_${a.l}` // considered a dupe

let found = new Set()
let filtered = values.filter(item => {
  if (found.has(makeKey_test(item))) return false
  found.add(makeKey(item))
  return true
})
console.log(filtered)
console.log("length:", filtered.length)
```

This will let you test if the set contains a version with the swapped keys but won't find "real" dupes with the same `i` and `j`

Comment: To make it clear i want to delete the second object when comparing the below objects: { i: 1, j: 2, l: 28 } and { i: 2, j: 1, l: 28 } where obj[0].i === obj[1].j &&  obj[0].j === obj[1].i

Comment: @KhaledInges this does exactly that.

Comment: i don't thing, we need to get an array with length of 15.

Comment: @KhaledInges I was using a simplified array in my example so it was easier to see exactly how it works. I've added your original and the length. It's 15.

Comment: elegent solution worked great with large array considering you used set in your solution. Thanks again!

Comment: as for my self I can not vote for you response, as I have < 15 of reputation. For that reason i have thanked you.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the values as combined key and check with a `Set` against for filtering.

```js
var values = [{ i: 2, j: 4, l: 36 }, { i: 4, j: 2, l: 36 }, { i: 0, j: 2, l: 28 }, { i: 0, j: 4, l: 28 }, { i: 1, j: 2, l: 28 }, { i: 1, j: 4, l: 28 }, { i: 2, j: 1, l: 28 }, { i: 2, j: 3, l: 28 }, { i: 2, j: 5, l: 28 }, { i: 3, j: 2, l: 28 }, { i: 3, j: 4, l: 28 }, { i: 4, j: 1, l: 28 }, { i: 4, j: 3, l: 28 }, { i: 4, j: 5, l: 28 }, { i: 5, j: 2, l: 28 }, { i: 5, j: 4, l: 28 }, { i: 0, j: 1, l: 20 }, { i: 0, j: 3, l: 20 }, { i: 0, j: 5, l: 20 }, { i: 1, j: 3, l: 20 }, { i: 1, j: 5, l: 20 }, { i: 3, j: 1, l: 20 }, { i: 3, j: 5, l: 20 }, { i: 5, j: 1, l: 20 }, { i: 5, j: 3, l: 20 }],
    s = new Set,
    filtered = values.filter(o => {
        var key1 = ['i', 'j', 'l'].map(k => o[k]).join('|'),
            key2 = ['j', 'i', 'l'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        return !s.has(key1) && !s.has(key2) && s.add(key1) && s.add(key2);
    });
    
console.log(values.length, filtered.length);
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not exactlly that, i just edited the question with the wanted result. Many thanks!!

Comment: Perfect @NinaScholz Many thanks, I definitely like your approach, however i just wanted to know this will behave with a large array.

Comment: just try it. it should work. a set is designed to be fast. if that is not fast enough, you could take an object with keys and `true` as value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const values = [ 
    { i: 2, j: 4, l: 36 },
    { i: 4, j: 2, l: 36 },
    { i: 0, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 0, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 1, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 1, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 1, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 3, l: 28 },
    { i: 2, j: 5, l: 28 },
    { i: 3, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 3, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 4, j: 1, l: 28 },
    { i: 4, j: 3, l: 28 },
    { i: 4, j: 5, l: 28 },
    { i: 0, j: 3, l: 20 },
    { i: 5, j: 2, l: 28 },
    { i: 3, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 5, j: 4, l: 28 },
    { i: 0, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 0, j: 3, l: 20 },
    { i: 0, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 1, j: 3, l: 20 },
    { i: 1, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 3, j: 1, l: 20 },
    
    { i: 3, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 3, j: 5, l: 20 },
    { i: 5, j: 1, l: 20 },
    { i: 5, j: 3, l: 20 } 
 ];
 
 let objData = values; 
 
values.sort(function(a, b){ return a['i'] - b['i'] || a['j'] - b['j'] || a['l'] - b['l'] ;  });

console.log(values);
let uniqueData = [], currentObj = {}, add;
currentObj = values[0];
uniqueData.push(currentObj);
for(let i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
   add = false;
   for(let j in values[i]){
      if(values[i][j] != currentObj[j]){
        add = true;
        break;
      }
   }
   if(add){
      currentObj = values[i];
      uniqueData.push(currentObj);
   }
}
console.log(uniqueData);
```